# Suggestion not showing in xml layouts with ctrl+space in Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am facing problem with android studio that suggestions are not visible on pressing ctrl+space inside layout .xml files. Editor always display "No Suggestions".
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I have fixed it by File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart Android studio.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try this

1. Close Android Studio then go to the folder where the android studio is located 
   Or you can go to the

   ```
   drive C -> users -> find .gradle file and do below things
   ```
2. `Find .gradle file -> In .gradle folder delete caches folder` 
   then restart android studio sync your files with Gradle...
   its work for me :D

Answer (score 3):

You can try `File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart`. That did it for me.

Hope it will helps you.