# Auto complete not working in android studio

Tags: android-studio, autocomplete

I am a starter in android development and I started off with `eclipse`.. But it started giving lot of problems. So I switched to `android studio`. Got it set up successfully and for couple of weeks it was ok. Now, for some reason, the auto complete feature is not working. It is not giving any choices while typing, so I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>. It says no suggestions. I browsed through similar queries and tried the following.

1. Disabling  Power Save in File menu.
2. Checking basic complete and smart type completion in IDE settings (editor)
3. Invalidate caches and restart.

But non of these seems to work.

Comment: I am having same trouble, even after doing all these and pressing ctrl+space multiple times the suggestions come for a second and get vanish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388983/5452338 follow this link. it's work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and you will get the drop down .

Comment: Tried Ctrl space also. It's also saying " no suggestions"

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and solved it.
 `Go File`> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` > Click at `Invalidate and Restart`

Then you can also check if **Power Save Mode** on **File** menu is disabled.

Source: [Android Studio - Auto complete and other features not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working)

Answer (score 4):

These following steps are working for me:

1. Close android studio
2. Go to `path/.AndroidStudio3.5/system/` delete caches folder
3. Start Android Studio

Comment: Finally, this is solved my problem.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should Try this way  `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart` or you can find solution by using **below link**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58214439/11404883

Answer (score 1):

In my case on Android Studio Artic Fox edition there were strange problems with autocompletion and suggestions because of old version of Gradle plugin. I have updated to

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21'
```

and it worked as expected. Hope it will be helpful for new visitors like in my case it would.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 21 I had tried
`$ rm -rf ~/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/caches/`

I followed all the steps from various answers and sources, still didn't get it to work. **Code completion** and **Syntax Highlighting** was not working.
I restarted using `Invalidate Caches` and did `Gradle Sync` atleast 10 times.

It was working in main flavor, but not in other flavors! In this project we have multiple flavors.

So finally the solution was found using
[Android Studio product flavors only recognized one out of two flavours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375205/android-studio-product-flavors-only-recognized-one-out-of-two-flavours)

Just selecting the correct `Build Variant` solved my issue.

Comment: Your answer is good, but you should try using formatting correctly. For eg. Syntax Highlighting doesn't need to be in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything inside `caches` folder

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio<version_x>\caches
```

and restart android studio