# Android Studio IDE weird behavior (graphic bug?)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I just started with Android development and installed Android Studio 1.4.1. Everything installed correctly and no errors were shown.

When I was just about to write the first lines of code Android Studio started to act really weird, like when I moved my mouse over the opened files it started to render/draw the code all over ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLJEr.png), [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CId5n.png)).

The weird thing is, this happens all the time after I ran Android Studio for like 2-3 minutes.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like a graphic card driver bug.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with your graphics card, but you should try to download the latest version of Android Studio and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still relevant but I fixed by disabling the "animate windows" Option in the setting:
[image: The setting page]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "sun.java2d.d3d=false" to "Android Studio\bin\idea.properties". This worked for me.

See here: [Android Studio is having a strange "cascading display" glitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531985/android-studio-is-having-a-strange-cascading-display-glitch)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
File -> Invalidate Cahses/Restart
```

hope it will helps 
or you can try another way like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58214439/11404883